# Inserting a polygon into MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL 8 table with a column called "coordinates" of type "polygon".

I am trying to insert a set of coordinates into it, like so:

```
INSERT INTO contract (coordinates) 
VALUES (POLYGON(
(34.786166422784426, 32.162676265661624), 
(34.720248454034426, 32.01024096292725), 
(34.816378825128176, 31.973162105505374), 
(34.86993717473755, 32.1338371543335), 
(34.786166422784426, 32.162676265661624))
)
```

which is giving me a "column count doesn't match value count at row 1" error.

Why is this? How do I properly format this query? And how can I explicitly pass an ESRI with it?

This, by the way, works fine:

```
INSERT INTO contract (coordinates, smart_contract_version_id) 
VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((   34.786166422784426 32.162676265661624 , 34.720248454034426 32.01024096292725 , 34.816378825128176 31.973162105505374 , 34.86993717473755 32.1338371543335 , 34.786166422784426 32.162676265661624  ))', 4326), 1)
```

Comment: There is no POLYGON datatype in MySQL. POLYGON is just a parameter that you can pass to the Polygon/MultiPolygon property functions. You can store it as varchar/text if you just enclose it into quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting wrong .. You don't need the sets of parens .. Note double parens are INTENTIONAL ..   AND the X / Y is denoted by a space .. Not a comma.  If it works without the "double parens"  It's because you don't have any insets -- "holes" etc ..

```
POLYGON((
   34.786166422784426 32.162676265661624, 
   34.720248454034426 32.01024096292725, 
   34.816378825128176 31.973162105505374, 
   34.86993717473755 32.1338371543335, 
   34.786166422784426 32.162676265661624
))
```

Comment: When I try to do it this way, I get an error at the latitude (32.16...): "32.162676265661624 is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting an identifier"

Comment: You MAY need to run it together .. IE `POLYGON((34.786166422784426 32.162676265661624,34.720248454034426 32.01024096292725,...`  Without line breaks and spaces .. It's been a while since I worked with GIS data .. But I remember it being finicky with that

Comment: No, same syntax error

Comment: What version on MySQL are you using .. I believe Polygon is > v 8+

Comment: I just looked at my code where I am creating a convex hull based on plot points and that syntax worked for me (run together)

Comment: In PostgreSQL, you'd need single quotes around that, but perhaps POLYGON is a function in MySQL?

Comment: Strike that .. I also have `PolygonFromText(POLYGON((  ..  data .. )))`  But that's in a data hybrid and may not work in your case ..

Comment: I am on MySQL 8. Using PolygonFromText gives me the same error on the lat of the first coordinate.